# how to display json array elements dynamically into select tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, json

I have a JSON array in the format like this

```
 "StoreName":["10001 Main ST","10002 Part1","10004 MyStore1","10005 M STR",        "10008 Centro","10009 MyStore 02","1001 G","1001 H","10010 Store main ROAD","10011 Central M Store","10012 En Department","10013 M Station","10014 Test Center","10015 SubStore1","10016 AA","10018 M part #","10019 Test A - 26032016","1002 B","1002 I","10020 Test Central B "]
```

and I have to access each element of it and display it into options in select tag as

```
<select id ="storeNm" name="name">
  <option>--Select--</option>
  <option>---Here store name list contents---</option>
  <option>---Here store name list contents---</option>
</select>
```

I am new to JSON and have to do it using javascript/jQuery so any help/guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: use .each to loop through your list and use append to insert selected into the select\

Comment: how can I do that can you show it with an example? @guradio

Comment: see below answer it covers all your requirements

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Iterate and generate elements using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method. Where elements can be [generate using jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-html-attributes).

```js
var data = {
  "StoreName": ["10001 Main ST", "10002 Part1", "10004 MyStore1", "10005 M STR", "10008 Centro", "10009 MyStore 02", "1001 G", "1001 H", "10010 Store main ROAD", "10011 Central M Store", "10012 En Department", "10013 M Station", "10014 Test Center", "10015 SubStore1", "10016 AA", "10018 M part #", "10019 Test A - 26032016", "1002 B", "1002 I", "10020 Test Central B "]
};

// create select tag
$('<select/>', {
  // set id of the element
  id: 'storenm',
  // generate html content by iterating over array
  html: data.StoreName.map(function(v) {
      // generate option with value and text content
      return $('<option>', {
        text: v,
        value: v
      });
    })
    // append the generated tag to body
}).appendTo('body');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Nice answer. But I suppose, besides text, having a value for the option would be nice to have.

Comment: @ThomasJunk : added value for option :)

Comment: I have used code snippet in script tag and even given the link for jQuery library but cant see the options as in the data list @PranavCBalan

Comment: @ShreyaRawal :  if you want to update options in existing select tag then do it like https://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/w2ps6zn8/1/ ...... or if you want to append then use append instead od html

Comment: @ShreyaRawal : although wrap your code with [document ready handler](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) always

Comment: Thanks I'll implement it, but still --Select-- option is not there in the list as in the output rest all the options are visible @PranavCBalan

Comment: @ShreyaRawal : just change `html()` method with `append()` :) , https://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/w2ps6zn8/2/

Comment: @ShreyaRawal : glad to help